# Evaluate For Loop for a fixed number of iterations

Tags: list-manipulation, infinite-loop

```
a = Table[Prime[n], {n, PrimePi[i]}]; b = Delete[a, 1]; p = 
 IntegerPartitions[i, 4, b]; Total[
 Times @@ Values[1/Factorial@#] & /@ Counts /@ p];
```

I need to loop this code for various values of $i$. How can I find, say, $i$ from $500$ to $1000$. I even need to make sure that the values obtained should be in the format

$p[500]=*500th~value~evaluated*\\p[501]=*501st~value~evaluated*
\\ .\\.$

and so on.

I tried using `For[i = 1; x = 0; i < 8,*body*]`. Here in the *body* I replaced the entire code mentioned above. Obviously it didn't work. Looking forward to your suggestions.

Comment: IntegerPartitions[i, 4, b] is certainly incorrect. As well as: Values[1/Factorial@#]. Values is used together with associations.

Comment: @DanielHuber the `Values` appears to be for `Counts` which _is_ an assocation.

Comment: @flinty  O.k. nobody is perfect!

Comment: @user75105 the whole thing could be done in one table as follows `Table[Total[
  Times @@ Values[1/Factorial@#] & /@ 
   Counts /@ IntegerPartitions[i, 4, Rest[Prime[Range[PrimePi[i]]]]]]
 , {i, 500, 600}]`

Comment: @flinty, will that give only fractions? I don't see any decimal values appearing

Comment: You never said anything about decimals. Just use `N[...]` on the result.

Comment: Thank you @flinty

Comment: @flint, but I did mention about output to appear like $p[500]=**,p[501]=**,..$

Comment: @user75105 yes but that's a bad idea. You are creating many variables when you should just use a list. But if you really want that method then you should really use a function: `p[i_] := Total[
  Times @@ Values[1/Factorial@#] & /@ 
   Counts /@ IntegerPartitions[i, 4, Rest[Prime[Range[PrimePi[i]]]]]]` then you can do `p[500]` for example.

Comment: Alright, that looks a tedious job. Thank you for the code